# Program crashing Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, vb6, basic

I am programming in Visual Basic and i have a program created that is a loan calculator. I pretty much have everything correct and it works and operates almost the way i want it too.

Here is my code so far:

Public Class Form1

```
Private MinAmt As Decimal = 1000
Private MaxAmt As Decimal = 200000
Private Drate As Decimal
Private Loan As Decimal

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '== Load the Rate and Terms combo, then 'click Reset
    For r As Decimal = 0 To 0.1475 Step 0.0025
        '== Add each successive value to the combo list
        cbxRate.Items.Add(Format(r, "00.00%"))
    Next
    For t As Byte = 12 To 120 Step 6
        cbxTerm.Items.Add(Format(t, "00"))
    Next
    btnReset.PerformClick()
End Sub

Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    '== Set the defaults, and clear my prior answers
    cbxRate.Text = "06.00%"
    cbxTerm.Text = "36"
    tbxLoan.Text = "10,000"
    lblPayment.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    '== Validate the loan amount (number 1,000 - 200,000);

    If IsNumeric(tbxLoan.Text) AndAlso tbxLoan.Text >= MinAmt AndAlso tbxLoan.Text <= MaxAmt Then
        Loan = tbxLoan.Text
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error invalid value")
        tbxLoan.Focus()
        tbxLoan.SelectAll()
    End If

    '== Calculate Monthly Payment as PMT(monthly decimal rate, term in months, minus amount)
    lblPayment.Text = Pmt(cbxRate.Text.Replace("%", "") / 1200, cbxTerm.Text, -tbxLoan.Text)

    '== Display formatted as money: FormatCurrency(blah blah blah)
    lblPayment.Text = FormatCurrency(lblPayment.Text, 2)
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    '== Confirm he means it, else cancel attempt to close.
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to exit?", "Close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

I tried to post a picture of my program so it could be easier, but apparently i don't have enough reputation points, but ill try to explain the best i can.

I would like to eliminate the problem of someone accidentally putting a Letter as a value in the "Enter Loan Amount" space. Right now if i were to put a letter "U" in the "Enter Loan Amount" space it would pop up an error (which is what i want), but it also crashes the program (what i don't want).

Hopefully that makes sense. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? I am still new to Visual Basic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're continue to calculate whatever or not the input was valid.

Exit the function by using Return after input was invalid.

```
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Error invalid value")
    tbxLoan.Focus()
    tbxLoan.SelectAll()
    Return
End If
```

Comment: Thanks so much, worked like a charm.  Kinda a silly simple mistake i should of seen. anyways thank you

Answer (score 0):

or just move the calculations to inside the If statement

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

    '== Validate the loan amount (number 1,000 - 200,000);
    If IsNumeric(tbxLoan.Text) AndAlso tbxLoan.Text >= MinAmt AndAlso tbxLoan.Text <= MaxAmt Then

        Loan = tbxLoan.Text

        '== Calculate Monthly Payment as PMT(monthly decimal rate, term in months, minus amount)

        lblPayment.Text = Pmt(cbxRate.Text.Replace("%", "") / 1200, cbxTerm.Text, -tbxLoan.Text)

        '== Display formatted as money: FormatCurrency(blah blah blah)
        lblPayment.Text = FormatCurrency(lblPayment.Text, 2)

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error invalid value")
        tbxLoan.Focus()
        tbxLoan.SelectAll()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are still executing the rest of the code. You need to exit that block. Make use of Return statement..

```
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Error invalid value")
    tbxLoan.Focus()
    tbxLoan.SelectAll()
    Return
End If
```